# Eclipse throwing error when I try to add breakpoint for debugging

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I added scala perspective in eclipse. Everything is working fine but when I try to add breakpoint for debugging it will throw error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Toggle Line Breakpoint".
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/ui/actions/BreakpointToggleUtils
```

But the same is working when i work in java perspective.